# Is this function concave?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The result of the command of Mathematica 12.3.1.0

```
FunctionConvexity[{u^3*Abs[Integrate[Exp[-I*t]/t^3, {t, u, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> u > 0]], u > 0}, u, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `Indeterminate`

is in discordance with [the affirmative answer at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390884/is-this-function-concave).
My try to check it is

```
NMaximize[{D[u^3*ComplexExpand[Abs[Integrate[Exp[-I*t]/t^3,{t,u,Infinity},Assumptions->u> 0]]],{u,2}],u > 0},u]
```

which returns the input.

Who is right: Mathematica or [fedia](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1131/fedja)?

Comment: `Indeterminate` seems a non-answer to me, neither right nor wrong. What does it mean?

Comment: @MichaelE2: You are not right. [The documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionConvexity.html) (namely, "Details and Optons" section) says  "Indeterminate neither convex nor concave". Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: You get a result for check with NMaximize if you add TargetFunctions->>... and FullSimplify .... But of course only a numerical hint. `NMaximize[{D[
   u^3*ComplexExpand[
      Abs[Integrate[Exp[-I*t]/t^3, {t, u, Infinity}, 
        Assumptions -> u > 0]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
    FullSimplify[#, u > 0] &, {u, 2}], u > 0}, u, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxIterations -> 1000, AccuracyGoal -> 4] `

Comment: @user64494  my result is `{0, {u -> 1180.5084240238904723}} `  working with version `"8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)" `

Comment: @Akku14: Thank you for your interest to the question and your work. Executing your code, I obtain `{0, {u -> 1180.5084240238902647}}` on my third attempt. Unfortunately this proves nothing 
 in view of`AccuracyGoal->4`.

Comment: My try `FunctionRange[{D[
   u^3*ComplexExpand[
      Abs[Integrate[Exp[-I*t]/t^3, {t, u, Infinity}, 
        Assumptions -> u > 0]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
    FullSimplify[#, u > 0] &, {u, 2}], u > 0}, u, y]` fails.